# Using Meta Box Plugin to assign URL to a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm a little lost here, hoping that someone can help. I'm using the Meta Box plugin for WordPress, and I'm trying to create a process for the user to select an option from a predefined list, and then assign a URL to that option as a link. Im trying to define the URL in a variable, and then call it in a function, but I'm still a little green on PHP syntax. this is my code now:

```
    <?php 

$article_url= rwmb_meta('orion_2016_article_url', 'type=URL');

if (rwmb_meta('orion_2016_article_source') != '') {
                echo '<a href= ("$article_url") target=blank>';
                echo rwmb_meta('orion_2016_article_source');
                echo '</a>';} ?> on <?php the_date(); ?>
```

Since the options are already predefined, it seems like assigning a random URL to one of the options should be pretty simple. Hopefully this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to to place variables you wish to `echo` inside double quotes or simply concatenate strings using `.` as in my example. Note that I didn't check the plugin's specific syntax, only general PHP syntax.

```
<?php 

    $article_url= rwmb_meta( 'orion_2016_article_url', 'type=URL' );

    if (rwmb_meta('orion_2016_article_source') != '') {
        echo '<a href="' . $article_url . '" target="blank">' . rwmb_meta( 'orion_2016_article_source' ); . '</a>';
    } ?> on <?php the_date(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Technoh! With the plugin syntax added, it works like a champ. Much appreciated!

Comment: If this worked for you please accept it as the official answer. Thanks!